# Can not connect to a mysql database from a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, remote-access

I have a google script to insert data to mysql table. I can not connect to mysql from remote connections. My host told me to add google Ip address to Access Host list for remote usage.
How can I find google ip address on my google script.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your question but... Have you checked the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#other_databases). `In order to create a database connection using the Apps Script JDBC service, in your database settings you must authorize IP ranges from [this data source](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt).`

Comment: is this connection correct?     var address = 'login.owlypia.org'; 
  var user = 'login_demo'; 
  var userPwd = '*******';
  var db = 'login_demo'; 
  var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);